# SQL Server - SELECT statement not returning results

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

Using the AdventureWorks database, I have been given a question to "**List the orders customer name, order status, date ordered, count of items on the order, and average quantity ordered where the count of items on the order is greater than 300**". However, my below SELECT statement does not return any results... What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT scpii.LastName + ', ' + scpii.FirstName AS 'Customer Name', ssoh.Status AS 'Order Status', ssoh.OrderDate AS 'Date Ordered', SUM (ssod.OrderQty) AS 'Count of Items', AVG (ssod.OrderQty) AS 'Average Quantity'
FROM Sales.CustomerPII scpii
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader ssoh
ON ssoh.CustomerID = scpii.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail ssod
ON ssod.SalesOrderID = ssoh.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY scpii.LastName, scpii.FirstName, ssoh.Status, ssoh.OrderDate, ssod.OrderQty
HAVING SUM(ssod.OrderQty) > 300;
```

Comment: MySQL can access AdventureWorks???  Are  you sure???

Comment: Please tag the proper dbms for your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You dont need to Group By on `ProductID` and `Orderqty`. If you do a groupping on them, you will be grouping it to a single order item level. So you will never be able to count more than 300
- Count of items on order should really be sum of the `Orderqty`.

Try:

```
SELECT scpii.LastName + ', ' + scpii.FirstName AS 'Customer Name', 
       ssoh.Status AS 'Order Status', 
       ssoh.OrderDate AS 'Date Ordered', 
       SUM (ssod.OrderQty) AS 'Count of Items', 
       AVG (ssod.OrderQty) AS 'Average Quantity'
FROM Sales.CustomerPII scpii
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader ssoh
  ON ssoh.CustomerID = scpii.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail ssod
  ON ssod.SalesOrderID = ssoh.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY scpii.LastName, 
         scpii.FirstName, 
         ssoh.Status, 
         ssoh.OrderDate 
HAVING SUM (ssod.OrderQty) > 300;
```

Comment: Still returns no data

Comment: @CameronCole are you sure that your data has orders with **unique** products more than 300 ? 300 is a very large number for an order

Comment: I'm not sure about the counting of differents products, i think the count is about items, try changing to `HAVING SUM(ssod.OrderQty) > 300`. Same for the COUNT you are doing on the SELECT clause.

Comment: @D.Smania Ahh yes, you are right! Because the question said "count of items on the order" I assumed I had to use the COUNT  function. Thanks!